# How does the Comparator compare() works internally for the method implemented below?

Tags: java

I have a custom comparator with the compare logic as below:

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        l.add("tendercoupon");
        l.add("giftcard");
        l.add("creditCard");
        l.add("tendercoupon");
        l.add("giftcard");

        System.out.println(l);
        Comparator<String> PAYMENT_METHODS = new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String r1, String r2) {
                if("tendercoupon".equalsIgnoreCase(r1)){
                    return 1;
                }else if("tendercoupon".equalsIgnoreCase(r2)){
                    return -1;
                }if("paypal".equalsIgnoreCase(r1)){
                    return -1;
                }else if("paypal".equalsIgnoreCase(r2)){
                    return 1;
                }else{
                return r1.compareTo(r2);}
            }
        };

        Collections.sort(l, PAYMENT_METHODS);
        System.out.println(l);
```

The output for this is : [creditCard, giftcard, giftcard, tendercoupon, tendercoupon].

I am not able to understand how is it sorting the methods internally ?

Comment: It is easy to understand,if you put debug point and check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comparison doesn't make much sense.

- Comparing `"tendercoupon"` to `X` will always order `"tendercoupon"` after the `X`
- Comparing `X` to `"tendercoupon"` will always order the `X` after `"tendercoupon"`
- Comparing `"paypal"` to `X` will always order the `X` after `"paypal"`
- Comparing `X` to `"paypal"` will always order `"paypal"` after the `X`
- Everything else is compared with regular lexical ordering

With such a bizarre comparison function, all sorts of bizarre sorting results will emerge.

If you're just trying to sort items in this ordering:

```
"creditcard",
"paypal",
"giftcard",
"tendercoupon"
```

Then you can just use the indices of an array to determine relative ordering:

```
import java.util.*;

class PredefinedOrderingComparator<T> implements Comparator<T> {
    List<T> predefinedOrdering;

    PredefinedOrderingComparator(List<T> predefinedOrdering) {
        this.predefinedOrdering = predefinedOrdering;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(T t1, T t2) {
        return predefinedOrdering.indexOf(t1) - predefinedOrdering.indexOf(t2);
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> l = Arrays.asList(
            "tendercoupon",
            "giftcard",
            "creditCard",
            "tendercoupon",
            "giftcard"
        );
        System.out.println(l);

        Comparator<String> comparator = new PredefinedOrderingComparator(Arrays.asList(
            "creditcard",
            "paypal",
            "giftcard",
            "tendercoupon"
        ));

        Collections.sort(l, comparator);
        System.out.println(l);
    }
}
```

Comment: The goal is to have tendercoupon in the end while creditcard always at the beginning. If there is paypal instead of creditcard have paypal at the top. So the output should come like this always [creditcard or paypal, giftcard, tendercoupon]

Comment: This will work no doubt. But the code i used is an existing one  in our application and i was curious to understand how is it working correctly.

Comment: @Abhilash28Abhi Well I already gave an explanation. Do you have any questions about it?

Comment: Ok..let me take this example of a list [5,4,1,2,3] with String values. Now when the compare() is executed does it just check each element once like comparing 5&4, 4&1, 1&2 so on for single iteration or how will it sort this list ?

Comment: @Abhilash28Abhi Sorting algorithms are an entire field of computer science that's far beyond the scope of a single Stack Overflow post. From what I've just looked up, `Collections.sort` implements the Tim Sort algorithm, which is loosely based on the merge sort algorithm. Those 2 terms should give you somewhere to start your readings

Answer (score 0):

I would rather do something like this:

```
    Comparator<String> PAYMENT_METHODS = new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String r1, String r2) {
            int result = r1.compareTo(r2);
            if (result == 0) {
                return 0;
            } else if("tendercoupon".equalsIgnoreCase(r1)){
                return 1;
            } else if("tendercoupon".equalsIgnoreCase(r2)){
                return -1;
            } else if("paypal".equalsIgnoreCase(r1)){
                return -1;
            } else if("paypal".equalsIgnoreCase(r2)){
                return 1;
            } else {
                return result;
            }
        }
    };
```

because in your version, comparing "tendercoupon" with "tendercoupon" would return 1 even though the strings are equal.